# Drop variable using corr = df.corr()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Doing a multi-linear regression I would like to drop one variable but do not know how to write the correct statement into `corr = df.corr()`.

Before using pearson for the correlation I have used

```
df = df.drop('location', axis=1)
```

but maybe there is a smarter way to do so?

Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 0):

In general, your proceeding is correct. If you prefer to keep the `location` variable in your original `df` and just remove it from the correlation table you can code this in one line:

```
corr = df.drop('location', axis = 1).corr()
```

Since `df.drop('location', axis = 1)` returns a dataframe you can simply apply any function that is included in the dataframe class like `df.corr()`.